# get the request made to rest service as a string

Tags: java, spring

I am making a request to my REST service as :

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":4,"name":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/operation/creation

I want to access this request as a String in my Controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/creation", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> posting(@RequestBody ModelClass modelClass) {

    // Code here 

}
```

Is there any way I can get:

String request = 
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":4,"name":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/operation/creation

Or at least the endpoint as a string in my controller class?

Comment: `String request`, String value should be closed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add HttpServletRequest as a parameter to the method. You can then getRequestURI or getRequestURL from the request object.

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity posting(@RequestBody ModelClass modelClass, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getRequestURI();  // gets the path component of the request
    request.getRequestURL();  // gets the complete request url
}
```